# How to add separator to menuBar in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

main window with menubar ,toolbar and statusbar

```
class TajirMWindow(QMainWindow):
    """Main Window."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Tajir/Home")
        self.resize(800, 400)
        self.centralWidget = QLabel("Hello, World")
        self.centralWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self._createActions()
        self._connectActions()
        self._createMenuBar() #Menus
        self._createToolBars()#tools
'''
Menu Bar function
'''
    def _createMenuBar():
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&File")
        outilMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Outils")
        menuBar.addSeparator()
        achatMenu = menuBar.addMenu("Bying")
        stockMenu = menuBar.addMenu("Stocks")
        menuBar.addSeparator()
        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Help")
```

when i run the code no probleme accur but i didn t get the separator

Comment: You ensured with the correct spelling of 'menuBar' ? You have two typos in there with 'menuBap' Just to ensure this is not the problem ;-)

Comment: the error is only here in the question / my code is correct  menuBar.addSeparator()

Comment: Could you drop the import statements and the definition of your QMenubar and QMainWindow, as there maybe a problem?

Comment: this is my code mainwindow class and function

Comment: QMenuBar doesn't support separators.

Comment: is there any solution

Comment: Just to make sure, you want vertical separators in the menubar itself, not a horizontal separators in the menus of the menubar....I got that wrong, and thanks to musicamente understood it now - deleted my answer.

Comment: @hamzachenni when you post/edit your code, please ensure that it's syntax is correct: for instance, the `_createMenuBar()` function is missing the `self` argument, and other functions like `_createActions()` are not in your code (and irrelevant to the example, so those lines should *not* be there).

Comment: Thank you for this note , Iadd self to my functions  '''def _createMenuBar(self):'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMenuBar doesn't support separators natively. It doesn't even support adding QWidgetActions, as they appear as empty actions and their widget are never actually shown.

The only solution is to create a "fake" action with an unique identifier, and bypass the drawing of the action using a QProxyStyle: we override [`sizeFromContents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#sizeFromContents) so that when the QMenuBar computes the sizes of its actions it returns an appropriate width, and [`drawControl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawControl) to draw a fake QFrame that is displayed as a VLine (like vertical separators in Designers).

[image: menubar with separators]

Important: this will **not** work on MacOS when using the [nativeMenuBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#nativeMenuBar-prop).

```
class MenuProxy(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # create a fake frame that we'll use as a source for the separator
        self.fakeFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(frameShape=QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)

    def sizeFromContents(self, content, opt, size, widget=None):
        size = super().sizeFromContents(content, opt, size, widget)
        if (content == self.CT_MenuBarItem and 
            isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QMenuBar) 
            and opt.text == '_'):
                # use the size hint of the frame to return the correct width
                size.setWidth(self.fakeFrame.sizeHint().width())
        return size

    def drawControl(self, ctl, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if (ctl == self.CE_MenuBarItem and 
            isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QMenuBar) and
            opt.text == '_'):
                self.fakeFrame.resize(opt.rect.size())
                frameOpt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionFrame()
                self.fakeFrame.initStyleOption(frameOpt)
                # the frame will be drawn using its own coordinates (starting 
                # from 0, 0), so we need to save the current state of the painter 
                # and then translate to the correct position
                qp.save()
                qp.translate(opt.rect.topLeft())
                # paint the "fake" frame
                self.drawControl(self.CE_ShapedFrame, frameOpt, qp, self.fakeFrame)
                # restore the painter to the previous position
                qp.restore()
                return
        super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)


class YourWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        sep = QtWidgets.QAction('_', self, enabled=False)
        menuBar.addAction(sep)
        # ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(MenuProxy())
```

Note that:

- since QMenuBar automatically ignores separator actions, `setSeparator(True)` must *not* be used for the separator action;
- the "separator" action has to be disabled, otherwise keyboard navigation will try to focus it;
- this will work even for menubars created in Designer, as long as you add a menu named with the unique identifier (the menu should be disabled as explained in the previous point);
- the `'_'` underscore is used to identify separators in the style, as QStyle has no direct access to actions (so we can't use `action.setData`), and using a special character is required because some Qt styles have the bad habit of setting mnemonics (the underscored letters that are used as shortcuts) by changing the text/label too, so if you use something like "separator", it could become "&separator", or even "s&eparator" if another object has the "s" shortcut already grabbed or you add more separators. Another possibility is to use '&' or '&&&' or any other unique non-alphanumeric character identifier like `'_#'`.